# Please help me understand the minor details

Tags: java

I just read about FILE I/O and now, I want to get my hands dirty. I want to:

1. Read input from console using a Scanner object with `System.in` object as it's argument.
2. I want to write that input read from the console into a file using a `PrintWriter` object.
3. Now, using another Scanner object that takes a File object as it's parameter, I want to read from the file and display it onto the console output.

I have tried to implement it in this way:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class A {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter("File.txt");
        File f = new File("File.txt");
        Scanner scan  = new Scanner(f);
        Scanner scan2 = new Scanner(System.in);
        String s;
        System.out.println("Please enter the input:\n");
        while (scan2.hasNext()) {
            s = scan2.nextLine();
            pw.println(s);
        }
        scan2.close();
        pw.close();
        System.out.println("****************************************");
        System.out.println("Displaying output:\n");
        while (scan.hasNext()) {
            System.out.println(scan.nextLine());
        }
        scan.close();
    }
}
```

In order to stop inputing from the console, I hit `ctrl` + `z`. **Is this the best, and the standard way of doing it?**

Also, if I need to enter blank spaces between the lines, how do I do it? It just ignores blank lines.

Answer (score 1):

## Termination

On your main question, "[...] I hit `ctrl+z`. **Is this the best, and the standard way of doing it?**"

I assume that you are using Windows `cmd.exe`, and therefore `ctrl+z` effectively means that the terminal generates a simulated `EOF` on `stdin`. Therefore, **yes it is the standard way**, although maybe not convenient for all users.

On Windows `cmd.exe`, `ctrl+z` generates an `EOF` on the `stdin` provided by the terminal. It is the same thing as `ctrl+d` on POSIX systems. This is the standard way how programs read - they read from their streams until they hit `EOF`.

There are literally thousands of programs that show exactly that behavior. That behavior is the precondition for programs to successfully interact with files and other programs using *redirection* with `<` / `>` and *pipes* with `|`. That behavior is shown by the simplest programs such as `cat`, `head`, `tail`, `sort`, `grep`, `sed` as well as more complex programs like `avconv`, `mplayer` and so on.

Waiting for a specific token *instead* of `EOF` is a *bad idea*. It will make your program behave non-intuitively and even crash when users use redirection and are not aware of that token. Even if they are aware of that token, it places an additional burden on them.

Waiting for a specific token *in addition* to `EOF` can be a good idea. For example, the program `bc`, the *binary calculator*, can be terminated with `EOF` but also by sending it a line with the text `quit`. You can do so if you want to add user-friendliness.

But it also depends on the nature of your input. If your program is to process arbitrary input, eventually redirected from arbitrary files, like for example, counting lines or words or characters, waiting for a specific token would be a very bad idea.

As soon as you support terminating a program not only with `EOF` but with a token, you need to consider: *What if that token can also be valid input?* Then you need to start thinking of an escape mechanism. Although this is a standard problem with standard solutions and not overly complex, for simple programs like that the additional complexity still is usually unjustified.

## Closing resources

It's good that your program closes resources.
However, resources should be closed not only in the good case but also in the bad case. Your program does not close resources in case an exception happens.

A program that simply uses a Scanner to read from `stdin` could be written like this:

```
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.Scanner;
import static java.lang.System.in;
import static java.lang.System.out;

public class ScanCat {
    public static void main(final String... args) {
        scanCat(in);
    }
    public static void scanCat(final InputStream in) {
        try (final Scanner scanner = new Scanner(in)) {
            tryScanCat(scanner);
        }
    }
    public static void tryScanCat(final Scanner scanner) {
        while (scanner.hasNextLine())
            out.println(scanner.nextLine());
    }
}
```

This uses the Java *`try`-with-resources* statement. The closing brace on the `try` block performs an implicit `close()` on the `Scanner scanner` regardless of whether the `try` block completed successfully or got an exception.

## Using `Scanner`

By calling `scan.hasNext()`, you ask if the `Scanner` has a *next token*. That is different from asking whether it has a *next line*. Simply speaking, a token is a sequence of non-whitespace characters. (That's actually over-simplified, but good enough for this situation.) When you use the `Scanner` for *reading lines*, you actually want to ask it if it *has lines*, so you want to use **`scan.hasNextLine()`** instead of `scan.hasNext()`. Same for your `scan2`.

## Code Style

Your method `main()` is actually quite long. Ideally, methods do just one thing. That keeps maintainability high. It can of course sometimes make sense to have just one method with everything inside if that is more concise in a specific situation, but having small methods (or functions / procedurs / operations / closures) which do just one thing allows for more reuse, easier testing and better readability of source code (as long as you give your methods good names).

Answer (score 0):

> In order to stop inputing from the console, I hit ctrl + z. Is this the best, and the standard way of doing it?

Definitely not. You should let the program stop prompting through your codes.

> Also, if I need to enter blank spaces between the lines, how do I do it? It just ignores blank lines.

You can decide you own "break-command" by simply doing this:
This is one out-of-the-box solution which differs from the conventional usage of `hasNext()` and `hasNextLine()`.

```
String breakCommand = "~end";  //Set a string combination which is unlikely to be used
Scanenr scan2 = new Scanner(System.in);
String input = "";

do{
    input = scan2 .nextLine();
}while(!input.equals(breakCommand));
//^Keeps prompting for input from console as long as input is not "~end".
```

In this case you can enter **anything** (except the breakCommand) you want (**including spaces and new line**).

Comment: Why should `ctrl+z` be a bad way? I guess the user is on Windows, so it corresponds to `ctrl+d` on POSIX, which is `EOF`. There are thousands of POSIX programs that terminate on `EOF`, it's a standard way: `cat`, `sort`, `grep`, `sed`, `awk`, `perl`, `cc`, `head`, `tail`, `more`, need I go on...

Comment: @ChristianHujer Can you be 100% sure the program written will only be used by programmer or someone who is computer savvy to know the key combination to terminate the EOF? When I write programs for my own usage, it is as user-unfriendly as it can be. But when your CEO wants your program to be used within the entire company. Are you going to tell the entire company "all of you need to learn ctrl-z" ?

Comment: If the CEO doesn't know how to use the command line, the CEO will not get a command line program but one with GUI or web frontend.

Comment: @ChristianHujer you are wrong then, because at least it happened to me. At least I would not want my users to terminate the program/input abruptly using terminating  key commands. and I don't think it is nice to down vote someone just because you are assuming what you insist is the world standard.

Comment: If the koans of UNIX do not convince you of the wisdom of terminating a program upon the end of input, I will also not waste my time trying.

Comment: By the way, the code that you've given crashes. `scan2.nextLine()` might throw `NoSuchElementException` in case there's `EOF` on `System.in`.

Answer (score 0):

I completely rewrote your progam and made various changes.
I hope you learn somthing from that code. :-)

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    File f = new File("File.txt");
    // I am defining the Writer, the Scanner and the Reader inside a try with resources statement.
    // This assures that all streams are closed properly even if an exception occurs.
    // Also I am not giving the file directly to the PrintWriter directly but instead putting a BufferedWriter in between.
    // This makes it so that if content is printed, it is not immediately written to the File, but instead is being buffered.
    // In general this is more efficient because the file has to be only opened once.
    try (PrintWriter fileWriter = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(f)));
            Scanner inputScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
            // Instead of using a Scanner for reading the File I am using a BufferedReader.
            // This one also buffers the content so it only has to be opened once.
            BufferedReader fileReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(f))) {
        System.out.println("Please enter the input:\n");
        String line;
        // In addition to using Ctrl-Z you can terminate the input by writing the line "exit."
        while (inputScanner.hasNextLine() && !(line = inputScanner.nextLine()).equals("exit")) {
            fileWriter.println(line);
        }

        // This line makes sure that all content that is saved inside the BufferedWriter gets written to the file before we read it again.
        fileWriter.flush();

        System.out.println("****************************************");
        System.out.println("Displaying output:\n");

        // Here I am simply reading the file using the BufferedReader.
        // Also I am reusing the variable line because it is no longer needed to scan the input.
        while ((line = fileReader.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line);
        }
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Also your blank lines seem to work for me. Maybe it's your IDE doing weird things. (I am using eclipse)

Comment: That program crashes with `NoSuchElementException` on `EOF` on `stdin`.

Comment: @ChristianHujer What do you mean with EOF on stdin? On what line does it chrash? And when does it crash?

Comment: The call `inputScanner.nextLine()` will throw `NoSuchElementException` in case there is no more lines on the underlying `InputStream` of the `Scanner inputScanner`. See [http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine--]. And since you're not asking the `Scanner` if `inputScanner.hasNextLine()` first, you cannot know for sure that you will get a next line.

Comment: `EOF` on `stdin` means that `System.in` has no more input to read, either because it was redirected from a file and that file ended or is empty, or because the user simulated EOF on the terminal using `ctrl+z` (Windows `cmd.exe) resp. `ctrl+d` (POSIX terminals and alike).

Comment: @ChristianHujer thanks. I fixed the answer. It sould work now.

Comment: @Quijx his down votes are casted without justification. Maybe we should just neutralise his unjustified vote by upvoting the other.

Comment: The blank lines did not work in his original program because he was using `hasNext()` instead of `hasNextLine()`.

Comment: @user3437460 I'm downvoting your answers because your answers are simply wrong. The only real problem with the OP's original code is that he was using `hasNext()` instead of `hasNextLine()`. You're suggesting solutions which do not check for the availability of the next token and thus are prone to throwing `NoSuchElementException` which is neither intended nor expected in this use case, and therefore your answers are wrong. Fix them, and I will remove my downvote or even upvote your answers.